# Convert String name into javascript variable name?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, var

Problem with example:

Variable name: `var product5519 = 10;`

I can get this name in the form of a String i.e

```
var str = "product5519"
```

Is there any way to convert it into variable name so that i can use the value assigned to

```
product5519
```

I know one way to solve this problem i.e using `eval(str)`

If there is any another way to solve it please tell?

Comment: What’s wrong with `eval` for this task?

Answer (score 1):

Once you are certain creating a global variable was the Right Thing to do, you can add your variable to the `window` object, like so:

```
window[str] = 42;
```

This works because variable lookups end up trying the `window` object if the variable was not defined in an inner scope.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky but if you wanted to make a global variable you could do:

```
var str = "product5519";
window[str] = value;
```

You could then access the variable like:

```
window[str];
window.str;
str;         // Assuming that there is no local variable already named "str"
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like:

`window['product5519'] = 'value'`

it may be better to have an array of products, depending on the situation ofc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an associative array:

```
var variables = [];
variables['product5519'] = 10;

console.log(variables['product5519']);
```